# CGI Script Send Mail error

Tags: cgi, sendmail, internal-server-error

Hopefully someone can help a user that has zero experience with CGI coding. Prior to yesterday, the following code was working fine when our clients would submit their orders. Then yesterday an internal server error message would appear in their browser.

When our hosting company did some trouble shooting this is what their error log was saying:

20130508T200031: www.4printer.com/cgi-bin/mailit.cgi
open |/usr/lib/sendmail -t -oi -oem: Permission denied
at /home/users/web/b643/ipw.i4printe/public_html/cgi-bin/mailit.cgi line 110

Unfortunately they do not support coding issues.

Line 110 of the code just says this:

```
$msg->send();
```

This is the entire CGI code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# webmaster@qnis.net

$date = `/bin/date`; chop($date);

# Read the Input 
read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

# Split the name-value pairs

@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
 if(!($buffer =~ /CUSTOMER/)){
   print <<"(ERROR_MSG)";
Content-type:text/html


 <center><font size='4'><b>No data was recorded. Please use your browsers back button and try again.
```

(ERROR_MSG)
  exit;
}

```
$mailprog = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";
$emailInfo = "";

open(MAIL, "|$mailprog -t") || do{ print "Can't open $mailprog!\n"; exit;};
  print MAIL "To: ctsales2\@4printer.com\n";
#   print MAIL "To: jim\@spiderbilt.com\n";
print MAIL "From: 4printWebForm\n";  
print MAIL "Subject: California Financial Printing Order Form\n\n";
print MAIL "This form was submitted on $date\n\n";
foreach $pair (@pairs) {

 ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
 $value =~ tr/+/ /;
 $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
 $name =~ tr/+/ /;
 $name =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

 if ($value eq "SUBMIT INFORMATION") {
Next;
 } else {
      print MAIL "$name: $value\n\n";
      $emailInfo = $emailInfo . "$name: $value<br /><br />";
   }
```

}
    close (MAIL);

```
$title='Perl Mail demo';
$from= 'info@4printer.COM';

$rcvd_cookies = $ENV{'HTTP_COOKIE'};
@cookies = split /;/, $rcvd_cookies;
  foreach $cookie ( @cookies ){
  ($key, $val) = split(/=/, $cookie); # splits on the first =.
$key =~ s/^\s+//;
$val =~ s/^\s+//;
$key =~ s/\s+$//;
$val =~ s/\s+$//;
if( $key eq "4printerEmail" ){
    use URI::Escape;
    $user_id = uri_unescape($val);
}
```

}

```
## Mail Header
 use MIME::Lite;

# SendTo email id

# create a new MIME Lite based email
 my $msg = MIME::Lite->new
```

(
    Subject => "4Printer.com Confirmation",
    From    => 'sales@4printer.com',
    To      => $user_id,
    Type    => 'text/html',
    Data    => '

```
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <div width="300">
                        <font face="Arial" size="2">
                            <p>
                            '.$emailInfo.'
                            </p>
                            <p>
                             Your order has been received and is being processed. <br /><br />
                             Thank you for your order!
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <font color="#5485a3"><b>California Financial Printing</b></font><br />
                            P.O. Box 25755<br />
                            Fresno, CA 93729-5755<br />
                            559.454.8414<br />
                            800.438.1449
                        </font>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

'
);

```
$msg->send();

print <<output;
Content-type:text/html
```

output

Any advice or input is greatly appreciated. I thank you in advance!

Comment: Did your hosting company change any permissions/configuration recently (i.e. since you last knew it was working correctly)?

Comment: Rowland - that is the million dollar question because it would appear that somehow the permissions may have been changed. Of course they don't want to admit it. I think there is nothing wrong with the code - I think, especially since it was working.

Comment: That's not likely to be something we're likely to know though(!) What have their tech support said?

Comment: They claim they haven't done anything on their end but after strongly insisting that they must have done something, our issue is being bumped up to a higher tier and they are now running some tests.